# Retrieve copy of signed document with certificate appened?

Tags: docusignapi

If you download the completed copy of a signed document from the web interface, you have the option to download a copy with the summary (certificate) PDF appended to the end of the signed document.

Is there a way to retrieve a signed document through the DocuSign api calls to get a copy of the signed document with the summary (certificate) appended?

Comment: Yes, please see the documentation for examples: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic%20Scenarios/Retrieving%20Envelope%20and%20Documents.htm?Highlight=combined

Comment: Here is the latest API recipie to download documents https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/get-an-envelopes-document-list

Answer (score 2):

Yes please review the **getEnvelopeDocuments** API [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/).

By default it downloads the envelope documents. To get the Certificate of Completion appended use the optional query parameter `?certificate=true`. Example:

```
GET v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined?certificate=true
```